# Using sed for extracting substring from string

Tags: regex, shell, sed, terminal

I just started using sed from doing regex. I wanted to extract `XXXXXX` from `*****/XXXXXX>` so I was following

```
sed -n "/^/*/(\S*\).>$/p"
```

If I do so I get following error

> sed: 1: "/^/*/(\S*).>$/p": invalid command code *

I am not sure what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ echo '*****/XXXXXX>' | sed 's|.*/||; s|>.*||'
XXXXXX
```

The substitute command `s|.*/||` removes everything up to the last `/` in the string.  The substitute command `s|>.*||` removes everything from the first `>` in the string that remains to the end of the line.

Or:

```
$ echo '*****/XXXXXX>' | sed -E 's|.*/(.*)>|\1|'
XXXXXX
```

The substitute command `s|.*/(.*)>|\1|` captures whatever is between the last `/` and the last `>` and saves it in group 1.  That is then replaced with group 1, `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion **awk** performs better this task. Using -F you can use multiple delimiters such as "/" and ">":

```
echo "*****/XXXXXX>" | awk -F'/|>' '{print $1}'
```

Of course you could use **sed**, but it's more complicated to understand. First I'm removing the first part (delimited by "/") and after the second one (delimited by ">"):

```
echo "*****/XXXXXX>" | sed -e s/.*[/]// -e s/\>//
```

Both will bring the expected result: XXXXXX.

Answer (score 0):

with `grep` if you have `pcre` option

```
$ echo '*****/XXXXXX>' | grep -oP '/\K[^>]+'
XXXXXX
```

- `/\K` positive lookbehind `/` - not part of output
- `[^>]+` characters other than `>`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '*****/XXXXXX>' |sed 's/^.*\/\|>$//g'
XXXXXX
```

Start from start of the line, then proceed till lask `/` ALSO find `>` followed by EOL , if any of these found then replace it with blank.